# Create md3 model in Blender 2.6

Tags: textures, blender, texture-mapping, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping

I am using Blender 2.6 to create a model in Quake III format (md3). I have managed to create a UV map and I the texture is mapped correctly in Blender. However, when the model is used in the game, the texture mapping is completely wrong. Do I need to do more than just create the UV map? The md3 file seems to have no texture alignment data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have found what to do. I needed to add the property "md3shader" to the exported object. Now it seems to work fine.